# I want something like facebook status update in Ajax with pagination using codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

Here is my controller "Control"

```
public function home()
{
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url().'control/index';
$config["total_rows"] = $this->pagin_db->record_count();
$config["per_page"] = 10;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data["results"] = $this->pagin_db->
fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('slr');
$this->load->view('index', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Here is my model pagin_db

```
class Pagin_db extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("searchf");
    }

    public function fetch_location($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("searchf");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Here is my view "index"

```
<div id="container">
    <center>
<div id="content">
   <div>
  <h1>Countries</h1>
  <div id="body">
    <table>
<?php
foreach($results as $data) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$data->sno."</td><td>".$data->location."</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
   <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</center>
</div>
```

After this what i have to do for adding ajax and the last posted city to be posted at first as like fb update

and dont worry the city is only upto 6 in database so only it is visible like that

Comment: Seriously? First do your job: Make a list of the companies, without AJAX, and then, ask about how to paginate them. Asking just for the whole code of a problem is like hiring someone without paying it. When you'll show something you tried and it's not working, then, ask what is your problem and you'll get add

Comment: really sorry chococroc i am just a student and one of my college project and i am not a employee of any company

Really sorry to just asking for code because i do no where to start the code itself and do no what to do with codeigniter so only any

if u have any links to learn about creating pagination without ajax means please send me i ll try if i have any doubts i ll ask here

Comment: XD, Ok, don't worry, but the way you did the question doesn't fit the rules of SO. My suggestion: First, create a normal page, without AJAX, and with pagination: http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/ When you'll have that, you'll be able of adding JS to make an endless scroller that load every page when you hit the bottom of the page. Do that, and came back with question with specific code problems, ;D

Comment: Thank you chocoroc i ll be back after implementing it

Comment: I have posted my question above now please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
You must have call ajax when user scroll down. here is example

In View
--------


    <script>
    var track_load = 0;
    var loading  = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".container").scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) 
            {
                if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false)
                {
                    loading = true;
                    var form_data={
                    start:track_load,
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "display_read",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: form_data,
                            success: function(responseText){
                                $("#your_div_id").append(responseText);
                                track_load++;
                                loading = false;
                            },
                            complete: function(){       
                            }
                      });
                }
            }
        });

    });
    </script>

In Controller
------------
$start=$_POST['start'];

$read=$this->temp_model->fetch_sort_details($start);
for($i=0;$i<count($read);$i++)
{
   //here is your feeds
}

In Model
----------

    function fetch_read($start) {
     $this->db->select("condition");
     $this->db->from("tablename");  
     $this->db->where("condition","apply");
     $this->db->order_by("fieldname","desc");
     $start1= ($start * 4);
     $this->db->limit(4,$start1);
     $query=$this->db->get();
     return $query->result();
    }

May these code helpfull for all other users of stackoverflow... 
thanks
```

Comment: initially the page is only loaded not scrolled. how do we get values in that case. what would be the jquery code? @kamlesh